# How are types constructed in clojure?

Tags: clojure

if i have a type stored in a variable

`(def ta java.util.Vector)`

how can I initialise a new Vector type with the symbol stored in a?

eg.
`(initialize ta params)` => `#Vector <params>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well your `ta` is an instance of [java.lang.Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html), so you can just use the `newInstance` method directly:

```
(.newInstance ta)
=> #<Vector []>
```

If you want to use parameters to the constructor, you can go via the `getConstructor` method with something like:

```
(defn build-constructor [klass & types]
  "Construct a new class instance dynamically at runtime"
  (let [constructor (.getConstructor klass (into-array java.lang.Class types))]
    (fn [& args]
      (.newInstance constructor (object-array args)))))

((build-constructor ta java.util.Collection) [1 2 3 4])
=> #<Vector [1, 2, 3, 4]>
```

Although this can be a bit more fiddly as you need to exactly match the parameter types in order to obtain the right constructor....